# Athena Partition Projection Custom Date Format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have partitions in S3 in hive-style format that look like s3://prefix/year=yyyy/month=MM/day=dd. I'm trying to create a partitioned projected table in Athena with one "date" partition.

I've keep running into parsing issues or creating tables that do not recognize any partitions. Below is the table that I would expect to work.

```sql
PARTITIONED BY (`date` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://prefix'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'has_encrypted_data'='true', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'projection.enabled'='true',
  'projection.date.type'="date",
  'projection.date.format'='yyyy/MM/dd',
  'projection.date.partition.format'="\'year=\'yyyy/\'month=\'MM/\'day=\'dd", 
  'projection.date.range'='2000/01/01,NOW',
  'projection.date.interval'='1',
  'projection.date.interval.unit'='DAYS',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://prefix/${date}', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1697473018')
```

It seems to me that assigning a `projection.date.partition.format` is the way to go, but I can't find any other examples of anyone using this.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?